# Controller and routes issues in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app where users can create courses, and each course has_one syllabus. How could I go about configuring my courses and syllabuses (I know it's Syllabi but apparently Rails doesn't) controller, and my routes, so on a course's page there is a link to create or show the course's syllabus, and a link back to the course from the show syllabus page?

In my routes I have:

```
 resources :courses do
   resources :syllabuses
   member do
  put :enroll #this is so users can enroll in the course
 end
end
```

Currently , so the course_id will be saved in the syllabus table in my courses_controller,  I have:

```
def create_syllabus
   @course = Course.find(params[:id])
   @syllabus = @course.build_syllabus(params[:syllabus])
  if @syllabus.save
   redirect_to @syllabus, notice: "Successfully created syllabus."
  else
   render :new
  end
end
```

then in my courses show page I have:

```
 <section>
  <% if (current_user.courses.includes(@course) || 
   current_user.coursegroups.find_by_course_id_and_role(@course.id, "admin")) %>
   <%= render 'create_syllabus' %>
   <% end %>
  </section>
```

then in my create_syllabus form (in my courses views folder) I have tried starting it off with:

```
    # I have @course = Course.find(params[:id]) defined in show in the 
                                                    #courses_controller 
   <%= form_for @course.create_syllabus do |f| %>
   <%= form_for @course.syllabus.create_syllabus do |f| %>
   <%= form_for @course.syllabus.create do |f| %>
```

and I get an undefined method error for each of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new `syllabus` in your `show` action of a specific `course`, you can add this to your controllers and views:

**courses_controller.rb**

```
@course = Course.find(params[:id])

# Build a new @syllabus object, only if there is none for the current course
unless @course.syllabus
  @syllabus = @course.build_syllabus
end
```

**views/courses/show.html.erb**

```
# Show the syllabus name if there is one, or show the form to create a new one

<% if @course.syllabus.name %>
  <p>Syllabus: <%= @course.syllabus.name %></p>
<% else %>
  <p>Create Syllabus:</p>
  <%= form_for([@course, @syllabus]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**syllabuses_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])

  # Build new syllabus object based on form input
  @syllabus = @course.build_syllabus(params[:syllabus])

  if @syllabus.save
    # redirect to /course/:id
    redirect_to @course, notice: 'Syllabus was successfully created.' }
  end
end
```

**course.rb**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_one :syllabus
end
```

**syllabus.rb**

```
class Syllabus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  attr_accessible :name, :course_id
end
```

Some things that I left out but you should still include:

- validations
- rerendering form if something goes wrong
- pulling things out into partials
- fixing bad code like `if @course.syllabus.name`
- pull out `if/else` logic into a helper
- …